# $\alpha$-minimal degrees for singular $\alpha$

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory, ho.history-overview, computability-theory

An important question in $\alpha$-recursion theory is whether there is a minimal $\alpha$-degree at $\alpha=\aleph_\omega.$

**Question 1.** Who first introduced the above question, and where can I find more information about it?

**Question 2.** Is there any singular cardinal $\alpha$ for which it is known there exists
 a minimal $\alpha$-degree? Is there any singular cardinal $\alpha$ for which it is known there is no
minimal $\alpha$-degree?

**Question 3.** What can we say about singular cardinals  of uncountable cofinality?

**Question 4.** What can we say about large cardinals (say at least inaccessible)?

Any good references are appreciated.

Comment: Interesting questions!

Comment: Try looking at some of Sy Friedman early works on admissibility and uncountable admissible ordinals.

Comment: I think Wei Li (currently at Kurt Goedel Research Centre, http://www.logic.univie.ac.at/~liw8/) knows about this problem. You may consider asking her about the state of the art and then share it with us.